# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException

Tags: spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I am using **HSQLDB** with **Hibernate version 4** and **Spring Version 4** in a **maven project**.
But for the same i am not getting connection object, **getting the following exception.**

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1263)
at com.mavenTest.dao.EmpDao.saveData(EmpDao.java:28)
at com.mavenTest.service.EmpService.saveData(EmpService.java:20)
at com.mavenTest.controller.LoginController.register(LoginController.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:276)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
... 41 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Whereas i am getting the **SesionFactory** reference, but if I try to get the session reference using **getSessionFactory().openSession()** getting the same error.

The configuration part in xml file as follows:

```
 <!--   =====================================sessionFactory==================================== -->

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
         <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mavenTest.model"/>
          <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            </props>
         </property>

   </bean>

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost"/> <!--  jdbc:hsqldb:mem:. -->
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100000"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="30"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="16000"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="0"/>
</bean>

 <!--   =====================================Bean dependency==================================== -->

 <bean id="empService" class="com.mavenTest.service.EmpService" autowire="byName"/>
<bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.mavenTest.dao.EmpDao"  autowire="byName">
  <property name="sessionFactory"  ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

I am not getting why the connection is failed. So **Please Guide**, What to be done in this.

Comment: Is HSQL runniing on your localhost? If not see [http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html)

Comment: Yes HSQL Server running on local, using command prompt.

Comment: Does it work fine with 'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.' ?

Comment: Yup running with jdbc:hsqldb:mem:. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the xml configuration its running and problem is solved. Changed code as follows:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:abc"/> <!--  jdbc:hsqldb:mem:. -->
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100000"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="30"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="16000"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="0"/>
</bean>
```